# Compare records of 1 column from 2 different Excel files, report what is missing or added

Tags: python, excel

I'm looking for suggestions while trying to compare two Excel files of data before running a monthly report. I would like this to be done in python.

The 2 .xls files should be identical (one is current month data and one is last month's data), but may have an added or missing record (as a row). I have an "ID" column that contains the information I am trying to compare.

**If there are any differences (added or missing rows), I would like to report any discrepancies.**

Ideally, this report would export as a .txt or a third .xls file.

Any code snippets or samples would be greatly appreciated!

Below is my code for doing something similar in .txt, but as soon as it hits the first discrepancy you are unable to see which record causes the problem.

```
f1 = open("AuditData.txt", "r")
f2 = open("AuditData2.txt", "r")

fileOne = f1.readlines()
fileTwo = f2.readlines()

f1.close()
f2.close()

outFile = open("AuditData3.txt", "w")
x = 0
for i in fileOne:
    if i != fileTwo[x]:
        outFile.write(i+" <> "+fileTwo[x])
    x += 1
outFile.close()
```

Comment: Without showing at least some efforts this question will be closed soon as too broad. I'm not familiar with python at all, but even though I see that Google knows more than enough to solve the problem you face)

Comment: @ Peter L. - I have the following code for what I have done, I'm trying to figure out the best way to share it, sorry, first time user to SO.

Comment: Add the code to initial question via `Edit` please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would look at [the pandas library](http://pandas.pydata.org/).  For example, if we start from two similar files:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> 
>>> df0 = pd.ExcelFile("id_data1.xls").parse("Sheet1")
>>> df1 = pd.ExcelFile("id_data2.xls").parse("Sheet1")
>>> df0 = df0.set_index("ID")
>>> df1 = df1.set_index("ID")
>>> df0
    A  B
ID      
1   a  e
2   b  f
3   c  g
4   d  h
>>> df1
    A          B
ID              
1   a          e
2   b  nolongerf
4   d          h
5   g          h
```

We can align them, look at the differences, and save the result to an excel file:

```
>>> a0, a1 = df0.align(df1)
>>> different = (a0 != a1).any(axis=1)
>>> comp = a0[different].join(a1[different], lsuffix='_old', rsuffix='_new')
>>> comp
   A_old B_old A_new      B_new
ID                             
2      b     f     b  nolongerf
3      c     g   NaN        NaN
5    NaN   NaN     g          h
>>> comp.to_excel("comparison.xls")
>>>
```

and so on.

Comment: Looks like the winner! Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: @S.Meyer: If you like this solution, you should "accept" this answer so it's clear at a glance to future visitors what solution you chose.

Answer (score 1):

`xlrd` and `xlwt` are both Python libs that I've used successfully for reading from/writing to an excel document.

Answer (score 1):

If the excel file only has one or a few tabs, your easiest solution would really be to save each separate tab as a separate csv and use an existing tool like `diff` which works right on the commandline in lots of platforms, or in many text editors like vim, emacs or notepad++.

```
$ diff file1.csv file2.csv
```

http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?diff

If you need to run this on lots of files, I'd still suggest using python only to act as scripting glue to call the unix diff program repeatedly using the sys library.

Apparently, python *does* have a "difflib" in the standard library, but I've never used it before or even heard anyone talk about it, but you're welcome to take a look at it: http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with a similar problem a few years back and eventually chose C# for my solution. After setting up a basing .NET environment, I was able to directly access the contents of the excel spreadsheets with very little effort.

If you're determined to use python, one approach is to use COM objects to access the details of each spreadsheet:
http://oreilly.com/catalog/pythonwin32/chapter/ch12.html

The reason I suggest C# is that .NET has classes designed specifically to facilitate access to spreadsheets.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7fzyhc74(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the note, Daniel. I noticed that COM was being used for similar situations but I thought based on the simplicity of my project, I would be able to find a work around. Your support is appreciated, I'll continue to research or just end up doing it in excel prior to the rest of the python scripting. Thanks again.

Comment: I failed to mention that you could probably also use VBA to do it.